# getting sheet names from openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a moderately large xlsx file (around 14 MB) and OpenOffice hangs trying to open it. I was trying to use [openpyxl](https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl) to read the content, following [this tutorial](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/optimized.html?highlight=load_workbook#optimized-reader). The code snippet is as follows:

```
 from openpyxl import load_workbook
 wb = load_workbook(filename = 'large_file.xlsx', use_iterators = True)
 ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(name = 'big_data')
```

The problem is, I don't know the sheet name, and Sheet1/Sheet2.. etc. didn't work (returned NoneType object). I could not find a documentation telling me **How to get the sheet names for an xlsx files using openpyxl**. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Use the [`sheetnames` property](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html#openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook.sheetnames):

> sheetnames
>
> Returns the list of the names of worksheets in this workbook.
>
> Names are returned in the worksheets order.
>
> Type:  list of strings

```
print (wb.sheetnames)
```

You can also get worksheet objects from `wb.worksheets`:

```
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
```

Comment: `wb.sheetnames` is the preferred spelling.

Comment: It would be so incredibly handy to have sheet name as a property in WorkSheet class.

Comment: @ÁronLőrincz Sheet name is avaialble on a WorkSheet objects as wsObj.title

Comment: This answer is out of date.  `get_sheet_names()` is now deprecated.  Use the wb.sheetnames attribute.

Comment: @Thruston thanks for heads up! Updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 12):

As a complement to the other answers, for a particular worksheet, you can also use cf [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet) in the constructor parameters:

```
ws.title
```

Answer (score 5):

**python 3.x**
**for get sheet name you must use attribute**

```
g_sheet=wb.sheetnames
```

**return by list**

```
for i in g_sheet:
    print(i)
```

**shoose any name **

```
ws=wb[g_sheet[0]]
```

**or ws=wb[any name]**
**suppose name sheet is paster**

```
ws=wb["paster"]
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned the earlier answer
you can get the list of sheet names 
by using the `ws.sheetnames`

But if you know the sheet names you can get that worksheet object by

```
ws.get_sheet_by_name("YOUR_SHEET_NAME")
```

Another way of doing this is as mentioned in earlier answer

```
ws['YOUR_SHEET_NAME']
```

Comment: **Note** `.get_sheet_by_name` is depreciated so you should only use the second option `wb[sheetname]` **also noting** that it is `wb` (workbook) not `ws` (worksheet) so neither answer here is completely correct.

Answer (score 1):

To get the names of the sheets from workbook;

```
List_of_sheets = wb.sheetnames
print(List_of_sheets)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for worksheet in workbook:
    print(worksheet.name)
```

Comment: There is no attribute `name` for the worksheet object in openpyxl, so `worksheet.name` would just return an attribute error. The correct attribute is `title` so the line should be `print(worksheet.title)`