# How to make python read multiple sheets on an excel file one by one

Tags: python, excel, list, loops

Stackoverflow

Hi python noob here.
I been learning python for couple of weeks so I don’t know if this is possible or even super easy.
I have an excel files with o lot of sheets, I have managed to create a python code that do all the changes I need to make on a single sheet and then saves it.
I just need to type the sheet name run it then type another sheet name and run it again etc …
Is there a way to make the code so it does all the sheets one by one when I run it?
I was thinking about creating a list with all the sheets name and using a loop but not sure how… thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use openpyxl module.
You have the list of sheets in openpyxl object, so you can run over sheets as by list.
You could find the solutions of similar problem here:

[getting sheet names from openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23527887/getting-sheet-names-from-openpyxl)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).